# Django use intranet server for uploaded huge media files

Tags: python, django

I have a Django project and I have a server on the internet (with Nginx and Gunicorn). I also have an intranet server (on the local network). I want to upload user uploaded files (media) in the intranet server. Is it possible? How?
I know users can't upload files when they are not connected to the intranet network, there's no problem this way.

Answer (score 0):

I think , you question is to transfer the file from one server to another ... which can be done with below link 
https://medium.com/dev-blogs/transferring-files-between-remote-server-and-local-system-133d78d58137

Or let user upload it to your gunicorn live server and write a daemon which will be transferring your files to your local intranet network.

If you need help in writing the daemon then ... let me know i will edit my answer

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need to users can directly upload their files in local server and download them from the local server via the Django app. All I want is to make the upload and download faster and without the need of internet.